# Login through parameterised query not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to implement mysql login through parameterized query but its not working below is the snippet of the code.

```
<?php
echo "hello";
$email=$_POST["username"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "toor";
$db="SQLINJECTION";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if (!$conn){
    die("connection failure".mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "success";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $pass);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$row=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
if($row){
    echo "found";
}
else{
echo "not found";
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Open [a manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) please. There's a sentence "The number of variables and length of string types must match the parameters in the statement. "

Comment: What error message are you getting? "Not working" is vague, more details will help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should only have 1 bind statement combining all the values you want to bind...

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $pass);
```

should be

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $pass);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email,$pass);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$row=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```